# How do I autorestart an exited process with exit status 0 in supervisord?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, supervisord

I am executing some PHP script with `supervisord`. Sometimes one of my processes is stopping with error log:

```
INFO exited: worker_push_notif (exit status 0; expected).
```

I already set in config `autorestart=true` but still, I have to restart it manually. Below is my full config:

```
[program:worker_push_notif]
directory = /opt/initproject/workers
command = /usr/bin/php /opt/initproject/workers/fcm_pushnotif.php
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stdout_logfile  = /var/log/initproject/pushnotif.log
stderr_logfile  = /var/log/initproject/pushnotif.err
```

Need help to handle autorestart for exit status 0. Thank you.

Note: Ubuntu 14.04, Supervisord 3.0. Already ask the same question on askubuntu but still not got an answer.

Comment: Anybody got solution for this ?

Comment: @RihardNovozhilov hai, it been a while, so I already forgot how to solved this. May you read this please https://serverfault.com/questions/163392/supervisor-always-quit-process-with-exit-status-0-not-expected

Comment: Thanks. Fixed by updating supervisor from 3.2.0 to 3.3.5